# What exactly is the 'recurring' PayPal IPN variable?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

For PayPal subscriptions, the IPN variable `recurring` "Indicates whether regular rate recurs (1 is yes, blank is no)."

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB0901HT

I'm not sure what this means. Looking at my log, it is always 1 for subscriptions. When is it not 1?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the meaning of the corresponding parameter `src` in the [HTML vairables for PayPal buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#recurring-payment-variables) - that may help understanding what does `recurring` mean.

> src - Subscription payments recur unless subscribers cancel their subscriptions before the end of the current billing cycle or you limit the number of times that payments recur with the value that you specify for srt.
>   Allowable values are:
>   0 — subscription payments do not recur,
>   1 — subscription payments recur. The default is 0.

For subscriptions the value of `recurring` will always be `1`, and for instant payments it will return blank.